# Surface Magnetism Horizontal z-axis Rotation issue

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I've been using the MRTK RC1 Refresh Development Kit. I'm using Surface Magnetism, to have an object follow the room's surfaces, with the following settings:

`Orientation Mode = "Full", Raycast Direction = "Camera Facing", Orientation Blend = "1"`

Everything works as expected on vertical surfaces, however with horizontal surfaces the object keeps rotating on the Z-axis without stabilizing according to the headset location. Has anyone else been experiencing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest filing an issue at the [MixedRealityToolkit git project](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity).